# Unable to connect Atlas MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb, express

Error I get when I try to connect **atlas mongodb** instance using **Express**.

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at Connection.openUri (/Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:825:32)
    at /Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:411:10
    at /Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1285:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:410:20)
    at connectDB (/Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/config/dbConfig.js:8:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aviralgupta/Development/NodeJs/MongoDB/index.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-a6to6lu-shard-00-00.nfmpr49.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-a6to6lu-shard-00-01.nfmpr49.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-a6to6lu-shard-00-02.nfmpr49.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-tvdhx4-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
Error in dbConfig.js
```

**dbConfig.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const connectDB = async () => {

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
            useUnifiedTopology: true, 
            useNewUrlParser: true,
        });


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.error("Error in dbConfig.js");
    }

}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

As it mentions that `you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted` I tried to add my current IP address but still shows the same problem.

Also this project was running perfectly fine a week ago, but now its not working and also one thing to note is that I did not changed my Internet connection when I builded, tested it but now its not working.

Answer (score 0):

For now, until you get a `static IP` just allow any `IP` address to avoid the hassle of adding the new `IP` every time.

[image]

You don't need to change the `ISP`(Internet Service Provider) to get a different `IP address`.Every time you connect to the internet, your `ISP` (Internet Service Provider) gives you an IP address.

Visit Mongo DB dashboard and change the IP whitelist to your current IP by pressing the button.

Comment: I already tried that but still the same problem persists.

Comment: At this point you should try contacting [`support`](https://www.mongodb.com/support)

Comment: please `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)` and see if env variable works correctly

Comment: Yes, I have already checked that MONGO_URL is correct, now I have raised an issue on GitHub let's see if the problem fixes or not.

Comment: try removing this object `{ useUnifiedTopology: true,  useNewUrlParser: true,}` or make the value false.there's something going with `useUnifiedTopology:true`

Comment: It did not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

The above comments are correct but if it still doesn't fix the issue
Update your systems clock.
The clock not been Updated can cause issues like this

```
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Answer (score 0):

if all the above solutions provided do not solve the issue. then check your network connection if you have data(MB), I mean your network provider(wifi).